# How to remove gear knob on Vauxhall Vectra

Tags: vauxhall, gear-stick, vectra

The chrome is peeling off my manual gear (shifter) knob. The car was first registered in 2004, and has a lift-to-shift knob. Can I replace just the knob (ie not the lever, cable)? Eg with something like [this?](https://www.halfords.com/motoring/car-accessories/interior-car-accessories/ripspeed-gear-knob-leather-aluminium?cm_mmc=Google+PLA-_-Car+Accessories-_-Interior+Car+Accessories-_-868349&istCompanyId=b8708c57-7a02-4cf6-b2c0-dc36b54a327e&istItemId=litpxq&istBid=tzwr&_$ja=tsid:94971|cid:868555876|agid:49387671572|tid:pla-455320850607|crid:203456299194|nw:g|rnd:5142122755942106129|dvc:m|adp:1o1|mt:|loc:9046288&gclid=CjwKCAjwmJbeBRBCEiwAAY4VVQxPLKMKrqylXIB7-0z2HUh1cveoe9BKwI8q6jcgmt-VhpW5Qhm7QxoC1b8QAvD_BwE). How do I get the old knob off?

Comment: The original knob is glued on. If you do get it loose with a bit of brute force (either twisting or pulling), fitting a replacement knob securely might be a harder problem to fix!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: first see if it is also screwed or not, whatever you do just try to not put any pressure on the lever itself. you may try heating the rod just below the knob

Answer (score 1):

Removing the gearknob on a Vectra C is literally a case of pull upwards. Some are really stiff, some are really loose. My Signum (based on the same model) is so loose it likes to slide off when the weather gets hot

Be careful when you do as there is a spring that sits between the lifter and the gearknob.